# Make image Icon Jump from one Label to another by Mouse click

Tags: java, actionlistener, jlabel

I'm quite new to java here , and right now i'm working on a program which involves the following actions. Lets say i have a 3 X 3 grid of JLabel. How do i load an ImageIcon and then move it from on label to another. For example, say each label is named as label_1 to label_9, and the imageicon is on label_2 . When i click on label_3,imageicon it should go to label_3

Answer (score 0):

Very quick example which you can adapt to your needs.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label" + i);
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");

                    JLabel clickedLabel = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                    Container parent = clickedLabel.getParent();
                    clearIcons(parent);
                    clickedLabel.setIcon(icon);
                }

                private void clearIcons(Container parent) {
                    Component[] components = parent.getComponents();
                    for (Component component : components) {
                        ((JLabel) component).setIcon(null);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                }
            });
            container.add(label);
        }
        add(container);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test frame = new Test();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Result should be following:

[image]